# Magento 2 Image not saving in Database

Tags: magento2, module

Magento 2 Image not saving in Database. My custom field is **`img`**

```
public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        /*print_r($data);exit();*/
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($data) {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Urds\OfferBanner\Model\Banner');

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('offerbanner_id');
            if ($id) {
                $model->load($id);
                $model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }
            try{
                $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                    ['fileId' => 'image']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('emizen_banner'));
                    if($result['error']==0)
                    {
                        $data['image'] = 'emizen_banner' . $result['file'];
                    }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //unset($data['image']);
            }
            //var_dump($data);die;
            if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == '1')
                $data['image'] = '';

            $model->setData($data);

            try {
                $model->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
                $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
                if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['offerbanner_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
                }
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
            }

            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['offerbanner_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('offerbanner_id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,add use **`Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList`** to this class.

**Then add below for add code for upload image**

```
try{

 $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
    ['fileId' => 'image']
    );
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
    $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('emizen_banner'));
    if($result['error'] == 0){
    $path = 'emizen_banner' .$result['file'];
    }
    //sucessFully upload
} catch (\Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: Hi when ever i update that time only i got error https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187566/magento-2-update-custom-module-admin-form-throw-error