# Magento 2 Update custom module Admin form throws error

Tags: magento2, module

This is my function, if i update it without image it throws the an error . Update with image it works Fine. How to fix this

```
**

1 exception(s):
    Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento/project/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Form/Element/Image.php on line 51
```

**

**Save.php**

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();


    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Banner\Model\Banner');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            //$model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }
        if(!isset($data['image']['delete']) || ( isset($data['image']['delete'])$data['image']['delete'] != '1')){

        try{
            $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                ['fileId' => 'image']
            );
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
            $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner'));
                if($result['error']==0)
                {
                    $data['image'] = 'banner' . $result['file'];
                }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //unset($data['image']);
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('$e->getMessage()'));
        }
    }
        //var_dump($data);die;
        if(isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == '1')
            $data['image'] = '';

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

**Edit.php**

```
public function execute()
    {
        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id');
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Banner\Model\Banner');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This item no longer exists.'));
                /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }

        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('banner', $model);

        // 5. Build edit form
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_initAction();
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Namespace'), __('Namespace'));
        $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Item') : __('New Item'),
            $id ? __('Edit Item') : __('New Item')
        );
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($id ? __('Edit Item') : __('New Item'));
        //$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New Item'));

        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep with below code and check,

You can check your code with below way,
1. If new image assigned, then go to if condition

```
(isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name']) )
```

and

If you are update image value go to else condtions,

So you dont need to worry about your field with no image.

```
<?php
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Banner\Model\Banner');

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            //$model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }
        if (isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name']) ) {

            try{
                $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                    ['fileId' => 'image']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner'));
                    if($result['error']==0)
                    {
                        $data['image'] = 'banner' . $result['file'];
                    }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //unset($data['image']);
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('$e->getMessage()'));
            }
        }else {
                if (isset($data['image']) && isset($data['image']['value'])) {
                    if (isset($data['image']['delete'])) {
                        $data['image'] = '';
                    } elseif (isset($data['image']['value'])) {
                        $data['image'] = $data['image']['value'];
                    } else {
                        $data['image'] = '';
                    }
                }
            }

        $model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id')]);
    }
    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have query.

Comment: You can use $this->getRequest()->getFiles() in magento instead of $_FILES.

Answer (score 1):

Your up-loader cpde should be under:

```
if(!isset($data['image']['delete']) || ( isset($data['image']['delete'])$data['image']['delete'] != '1')){

    $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                    ['fileId' => 'image']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner'));
                    if($result['error']==0)
                    {
                        $data['image'] = 'banner' . $result['file'];
                    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you please update Full function

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Check my updated question i got this error syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Still i got a same error Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the method `getElementHtml()` from line:

```
if ((string)$this->getValue()) {
```

where value is your image. There should be string (path to image) not an array. You should debug from where come array-type value and what is it?

You can try this code, I think it should work, but I not able to test it without a whole module:

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    if ($data) {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Namespace\Banner\Model\Banner');
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id');
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            //$model->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        }

        if (!empty($data['image']) && (!isset($data['image']['delete']) ||
            (isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] != '1'))
        ) {
            try {
                $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                    ['fileId' => 'image']
                );
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
                $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('banner'));
                if ($result['error'] == 0) {
                    $data['image'] = 'banner' . $result['file'];
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                //unset($data['image']);
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('$e->getMessage()'));
            }
        } elseif (isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == '1') {
            $data['image'] = '';
        }

        $model->addData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Banner has been saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Banner.'));
        }

        $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['banner_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('banner_id')]);
    }

    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just insert given below code before '`$model->setData($data);`' in your `'save.php'` file.

```
if(isset($data['image_url']['value']))
{
    $data['image_url'] = $data['image_url']['value'];
}
```